# percentage of entries who are only in one table, only in the second table and in both tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, exists

I have two tables with a common key (user_Id), and I'm trying to query a result that shows the 
***percentage*** of users (users being user_Id) that are only present in the **first** table (PC), ***percentage*** of users that are only present in the **second** table (phone), and ***percentage*** of users that are present in **both** tables. The total percentage should add up to 100%.

```
Table name: PC
user_Id     Page
1322       page_1_PC
7223       page_20_PC    
1032       page_7_PC
366        page_3_PC 
....
```

```
Table name: phone
user_Id     Page
123       page_1_phone
300       page_72_phone   
1322      page_7_phone
3662      page_3_phone
....
```

Desired output would be something like this:

```
platform     percentage
PC_only      23%
phone_only   36%   
both         41%
....
```

The furthest I've gotten is this below which just shows the sum of users present in one table and not the other, but i'm stuck. Preferably to not use UNION as I do not want to query the table numerous times:

```
SELECT COUNT(user_Id) AS PC_only FROM PC WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM phone WHERE PC.user_Id = phone.user_Id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

```
select count(*) as total_entries, sum(pc) as in_pc, sum(phone) as in_phone,
       avg( pc = 1 and phone = 0 ) as in_pc_only,
       avg( phone = 1 and pc = 0 ) as in_phone,
       avg( pc = 1 and phone = 1 ) as in_both
from ((select distinct user_id, 1 as pc, 0 as phone
       from pc
      ) union all
      (select distinct user_id, 0, 1
       from phone
      ) 
     ) p;
```

The `distinct` is not needed in the subqueries, if you know that `user_id`s are unique in each table.

Answer (score 0):

As of MySQL 8 you can use `SUM OVER` to get the total count and thus compute the percentage:

```
select
  user_id in (select user_id from pc) as in_pcs,
  user_id in (select user_id from phones) as in_phones,
  count(*) / sum(count*) over () * 100 as percentage
from users
group by in_pcs, in_phones
order by in_pcs, in_phones;
```

If you want to exclude users that are in neither table, add `having in_pcs or in_phones` after the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: I get it so far, but how is the 'from users' subquery created? Or 'users' table

Comment: You don't have a users table??? Where then does the `user_id` stem from??? When you said "tables with a common key" and it's name was `user_id`, I assumed of course that you are talking of a foreign key to some users table.  If this table is missing from your database, then your database is incomplete. I suggest you fix it. Create a user table, decide whether you want 1:n relations to phone and pc and create columns, tables, and foreign keys accordingly.If you want to stay with your inferior model, then use `(select user_id from pc union select user_id from phones)` to get all users involved.